# How to iterate till the last page of a website & write data row-by-row in a .csv file too?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I am trying to scrape some indeed job postings for personal stuff (code below), however I currently have to go until the last page to find out what its "index" or page number is, then I am able to iterate from first to the last page.

I wanted to have it automatic, where I only provide the URL and rest the function takes care. Could anyone help me out? Also, since I will scraping couple 100 of pages, I fear that I will get kicked out, so I wanted make sure to get as much data as possible, so I have writing to a csv file like in the example below. Is there a better way to do that too?

Indeed didn't give me an API key so this is the only method I know. Here is the code:

```r
## squencing the pages based on the result (here i just did 1 page to 5th page)
page_results <- seq(from = 10, to = 50, by = 10)

first_page_url <- "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=United+States"

for(i in seq_along(page_results)) {

   Sys.sleep(1)
   url <- paste0(first_page_url, "&start=", page_results[i]) #second page will have url+&start= 20 and so on.

   page <- xml2::read_html(url)

   #### 
   #bunch of scraping from each page, method for that is implemented already
   #....
   ####

   print(i) #prints till fifth page, so i will print 1 to 5

   #I also wanted to write CSV line by line so if some error happens I atleast get everythinh pre-error
   # do you anything efficient than this? 
   write.table(as.data.frame(i), "i.csv", sep = ",", col.names = !file.exists("i.csv"), append = T)
}
```

Comment: I think the manual approach where you decide to give the page start and page end makes more sense, and "scraping friendly" because you can control how much pages you want to get (plus respects the company servers). You know after a while you see same job descriptions. So stick with current approach in my opinion. About writing the .csv file per iteration, I think that's fine. Someone better than me should definitely say something. Because I don't have enough knowledge in R yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this advice, and wated to close this answer to reduce the open question. So answered my own question. Thank you SO community to always helping out.

"I think the manual approach where you decide to give the page start and page end makes more sense, and "scraping friendly" because you can control how much pages you want to get (plus respects the company servers). You know after a while you see same job descriptions. So stick with current approach in my opinion. About writing the .csv file per iteration, I think that's fine. Someone better than me should definitely say something. Because I don't have enough knowledge in R yet." – UltaPitt